# How to call random number from contact list? [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

Using [`FlutterPhoneDirectCaller`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phone_direct_caller), I'm looking for a way to randomly selected phone number from contact list and make a direct call.

`getContacts()` worked properly getting all the phone numbers from my phone, though I'm having trouble making var list for randomly selecting number from the list.

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter_phone_direct_caller/flutter_phone_direct_caller.dart';
    
    var contacts = ContactsService.getContacts();
    var list = [contacts];
      final _random = new Random();
    var element = list[_random.nextInt(list.length)];
    
    void checkContactPermission() async {
      var status = await Permission.contacts.status;
      if (status.isGranted) {
        FlutterPhoneDirectCaller(_random.nextInt(list.length));
      }
```

Comment: can you try with `list[_random.nextInt(list.length-1)`

Comment: I just tried and got 'The class 'FlutterPhoneDirectCaller' has a constructor that takes no arguments'. It's recommening me to remove some extra positional arguement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the contacts, you need to pass number on `FlutterPhoneDirectCaller`. Based on [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phone_direct_caller#example), you need to use like.

```dart
  const number =  _random.nextInt(list.length - 1);
  bool res = await FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber(number);
```