# How to call randomly selected number from contact list in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-packages

```
import 'package:flutter_phone_direct_caller/flutter_phone_direct_caller.dart';
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';

void checkContactPermission() async {
  var status = await Permission.contacts.status;
  var contacts = ContactsService.getContacts();
  var list = [contacts];
  var randomItem = (list.shuffle());
  if (status.isGranted) {
    FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber('randomItem');
  }
  if (!status.isGranted) {
    PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await Permission.contacts.request();
    if (status.isDenied) {
      PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await Permission.contacts.request();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my code to call randomly selected number from contact list yet it is calling a same number that isn't even on the contact list. What should I change?
Thanks in advance

Comment: When I change it to FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber(randomItem); the Android Studio shout 'This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used. I tried so many different ways but nothing seems to work

Comment: you already posted question and accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71037849/how-to-call-random-number-from-contact-list-flutter)

Comment: I've tried that and it seems like it worked but wasn't able to pick a random number from a contact list. Sorry for the second question. Once someone answer the question, I'm not eligible to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dart:math package in Flutter to generate a random number between 1 and the size of the contactList, then just call the random contact by the random index generated.

```
import 'dart:math';

getRandomContact(List<Contact> contactsList){
   var random = new Random();
   var randomContactIndex = random.nextInt(contactsList.length);
   return contactsList[randomContactIndex];
}
```

You can call it like:

```
Contact randomContact = getRandomContact(contactsList);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<void> checkContactPermission() async {
  var status = await Permission.contacts.status;
  if (status.isGranted) {
    var contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts();
    var list = contacts;
    list.shuffle();
    var randomItem = (list.first.phones?.first.value);
    await FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber('$randomItem');
  }
  if (!status.isGranted) {
    PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await Permission.contacts.request();
    if (status.isDenied) {
      PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await Permission.contacts.request();
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is what I found to be working